# SQL calculate timediff between intervals including a time from a separate table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date

I have 2 different tables called observations and intervals.

observations:

```
id | type,     |   start
------------------------------------
1  | classroom | 2017-06-07 16:18:40
2  | classroom | 2017-06-01 15:12:00
```

---

intervals:

```
+----+----------------+--------+------+---------------------+
| id | observation_id | number | task |       time          |
+----+----------------+--------+------+---------------------+
|  1 |              1 |      1 |    1 | 07/06/2017 16:18:48 |
|  2 |              1 |      2 |    0 | 07/06/2017 16:18:55 |
|  3 |              1 |      3 |    1 | 07/06/2017 16:19:00 |
|  4 |              2 |      1 |    3 | 01/06/2017 15:12:10 |
|  5 |              2 |      2 |    1 | 01/06/2017 15:12:15 |
+----+----------------+--------+------+---------------------+
```

---

I want a view that will display:

```
observation_id | time_on_task (total time in seconds where task = 1)
       1       | 13
       2       | 5
```

So I must first check to see if the first observation has task = 1, if it is I must record the difference between the current interval and the start from the observations table, then add that to the total time. From there on after if the task = 1, I just add the time difference from the current interval and previous interval.

I know I can use:

```
select observation_id, TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(max(time),min(time)))
from your_table
group by observation_id
```

to find the total time in the intervals table between all intervals outside of the first one. 
But 
1. I need to only include interval times where task = 1. (The endtime for the interval is the one listed)
2. Need the timediff between the first interval and initial start (from observations table) if number = 1

Comment: I dont understand how you achive that result. How you get `{ 13, 5 }` seconds with that data?

Comment: 16:18:40 - 16:18:48, 16:18:55 - 16:19:00, = 13 seconds total (for observation_id =1). 15:12:10 - 15:12:15 = 5 seconds total(for observation_id =2). Were only counting where task = 1. So where task = 1, we have the end time that we must compare to the previous interval and add those seconds to the total.

Comment: But `07/06/2017 16:18:55` isnt task 1

Comment: Right but the last number is where the current observation starts. The time under interval id = 3 has task = 1 which contains it's end time = 16:19:00. This should then be compared with 16:18:55 which is the interval endtime right before the current interval. When comparing times, we only have the end time. We look one backwards for the previous end time (our current start time). Also,  sorry if those look like subtraction signs. They are meant to represent thru (eg 16:18:55 thru 16:19:00).

Answer (score 0):

I'm still new to the Stackoverflow community, but you could try to use SQL

```
LAG() function
```

For instance 
Using an outer Select Statement

```
SELECT COl1, COL2, (DATEDIFF(mi, Inner.prevtime, Currentdatetime,0)) AS Difference 
FROM ( SELECT LAG(Created_Datetime) OVER (ORDER BY Created_Datetime) AS prevtime 
        From MyTable 
        Where SomeCondition) as Inner
```

Sorry if it looks goofy, still trying to learn to format code here.
https://explainextended.com/2009/03/12/analytic-functions-optimizing-lag-lead-first_value-last_value/

Hope it helps

Comment: MySQL doesnt have `LAG()` function